# Highcharts : Mouse Over on Legend throwing error in LWC Component

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lwc

when mouse is over the legend it is throwing an error as "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'MouseEvent': member sourceCapabilities is not of type InputDeviceCapabilities.
throws at [https://salesforce.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/7p9HLMpgnV2GO9MqZhXGUw/aura_prod.js:37:97048"](https://salesforce.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/7p9HLMpgnV2GO9MqZhXGUw/aura_prod.js:37:97048%22)

code :

`
Highcharts.chart(container, {
chart: {
type: 'pie',
//backgroundColor: '#c9dbeb',
options3d: {
enabled: true,
alpha: 45,
beta: 0
}
},
title: {
text: 'Pie Chart',
style: {
color: 'black',
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '30px',
fontFamily: 'calibri'
}
},
credits: {
enabled: false
},
exporting: {
enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
pointFormat: '{series.name}: **{point.percentage:.1f}%**'
},
accessibility: {
point: {
valueSuffix: '%'
}
},
plotOptions: {
pie: {
allowPointSelect: true,
cursor: 'pointer',
depth : 35,
//size: 300,
dataLabels: {
style: {
width: '90px'
},

```
                        enabled: true,
                        distance: -60,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        backgroundColor: 'black',
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: '#AAA',
                        alignTo: 'toPlotEdges',
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>   {point.percentage:.0f} %'
                    },
                    showInLegend: true,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'right',
                layout: 'vertical',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                symbolRadius: 0
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 61.41,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Internet Explorer',
        y: 11.84
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.85
    }, {
        name: 'Edge',
        y: 4.67
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.18
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        y: 7.05
    }]
            }],
        },

    );
```

`

Comment: Hi @SFDC Person, Your code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/230vryn8/ Could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: i tried this code in jsfiddle but there it is working fine. but the issue coming when i am taking the mouse over the legends.

Comment: in vs code i am facing this

Comment: Hi @SFDC Person, So this problem is probably not related with Highcharts. Have you tested your code in a different environment?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek i am able to solve the problem and that was related to highcharts onlyi will share the code. Thanks for Prompt reply